# Два действия в событии phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Нужно за одно событие совершить два действия.

> TRUNCATE top10;
>   INSERT INTO top10 SELECT * FROM top ORDER BY ball DESC LIMIT 10;

[image: пик1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Говорят ошибка в разделителе " ; ". Но у меня они уже стоят.

чтояделаюнетак ?

Делить на 2 события не хочу.

Comment: посмотрите примеры в документации. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html особенно в конце, там где в событии выполняется более одного действия. там используется блок begin / end

Comment: @Mike , Спасибо!

Comment: Truncate table top10;